# Deploying to Scratch Org in Jenkins pipeline with ant

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, ant, jenkins, jenkinsfile

I have a Jenkins script to generate a scratch org, make a user for that scratch org along with a password. When I try to deploy using that username and password I get

`build/lib/deploy.xml:26: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.`

While running this command

`deploy -Dsf.username=test-b1jpm0udc52d@example.com '-Dsf.password=hwmmA0dcpj^yz00D2D000000EJOg!AQwAQBkmxFalTKIXDeFfwAhEBIC3VCeKV8ebz9loGQF1WfjdUrAIEXjFALfDyF2qrI4aVxotSyBh8YgetMrAsQq7yqTxq0gv' -Dsf.namespace=TCADLL -Dsf.developerOrg=f`

My assumption is that the token I'm using isn't actually the one needed to deploy, as the one I use for my dev org is much shorter.

The code to generate the scratch org, user, and password are here.

```
stage('Generate Test Scratch Org') {
            rc = command "${sfdx} force:org:create --targetdevhubusername ${DEV_HUB_USRNM} --definitionfile ${SCRATCH_ORG_DEF} --setalias ${SCRATCH_ORG_ALIAS} --wait 10 --durationdays 1"
            if (rc) {
                error("Unable to create scratch org")
            }
        }
stage('Generate User for Scrach Org') {
            rc = command "${sfdx} force:user:create --setalias ${SCRATCH_USR_ALIAS} --targetusername ${SCRATCH_ORG_ALIAS} --targetdevhubusername ${DEV_HUB_USRNM}"
            if (rc) {
                echo "Wasn't able to make user for scratch org"
                TESTS_FAILED = true
            }
        }
stage('Generate Password for Scrach Org User') {
            rc = command "${sfdx} force:user:password:generate --targetusername ${SCRATCH_ORG_ALIAS}"
            if (rc) {
                echo "Couldn't assign password to user"
                TESTS_FAILED = true
            }
        }
stage('Ant deploy to org') {
            details = sh returnStdout: true, script: "${sfdx} force:user:display --targetusername ${SCRATCH_ORG_ALIAS} --json"
            def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
            def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(details)
            rc = command "${ant} -f ${BUILD_PATH} deploy -Dsf.username=${response.result.username} -Dsf.password=${response.result.password}${response.result.accessToken} -Dsf.namespace=${NAMEASPACE} -Dsf.developerOrg=f"
            if (rc) {
                echo "Couldn't deploy to org"
                TESTS_FAILED = true
            }
        }
```

If anyone has any suggestions on something I might've missed, or has a way to access the proper token I'd be thrilled to listen. I'm not using the sfdx:deploy or whatever function because our package isn't an SFDX project so it doesn't like the layout we have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use `sfdx` commands instead of the old `ant`.

`sfdx` still will be able to deploy your classic metadata package using a [sfdx:mdapi:deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm#cli_reference_force_mdapi_deploy) command.

> Use the mdapi commands to retrieve and deploy Metadata
> API–formatted files that represent components in an org, or to convert
> Metadata API–formatted metadata into the source format used in
> Salesforce DX projects.

run `sfdx:mdapi:deploy` set as target to which metadta should be deployed

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'd tried the mdapi once before but ran into a bunch of issues (hence why I was giving ant a go). Since this was providing about as many headaches I took another swing at it and it started working (mostly) so thanks!